# TestUnit --> stubbing rails controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing, testunit

I have a rails controller with the following logic and syntax method

```
def index
  if get_submission
    render :action => :workspace
  else
    flash[:notice] = t('flashes.no_more_submissions')
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

...

def get_submission
  ...
end
```

In my testunit functional test, I'd like to stub out get_submission so that it automatically returns false. I was hoping

```
controller.stubs(:get_submission) { false }
```

would do the trick, but no joy. I'm coming from an rspec background, very little experience with testunit. Any suggestions appreciated.

Cheers...

Comment: and the error you get is what? did you try ```@controller``` instead?